# [From Artin page 340]Question about quotient ring construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, proof-explanation

In Artin *Algebra*, page 340, Example 11.5.7 it said that if we quotient out $\delta^2-3$ in the field $\mathbb F_{11}$ to add two abstract square roots of 3, since we are not told that these square roots are $5$ and $-5$, we know that $\delta-5$ and $\delta+5$ are not zero. But since $\delta^2-3=0$, $(\delta-5)(\delta+5)$ is zero. And it cannot happen in a *field*.

So does it mean that in a ring but not a field we can get a $0$ from 2 non zero element? If so, could someone give me a such example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just observed that the quotient ring $\Bbb{F}_{11}[\delta]/\langle \delta^2-3\rangle$ is not a field. Nothing wrong with that. The ideal you moded out is not a maximal one, as it is contained in two bigger ideals - one  generated by $\delta-5$ the other by $\delta+5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the concept of a zero divisor: these are non-zero elements $a$ for which there exist a non-zero $b$ such that $ab = 0$. These do not exist in fields since fields are a subset of those special rings known as integral domains which have no zero divisors.

As you remarked, the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ where $m$ is not prime is a classic example. Any element $g$ with $(g, m) \neq 1$ is a zero divisor. For example, $4$ in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$ is a zero divisor since $4 * 7 = 0$.

Comment: Many thanks! But by the way I have a new question...That is: If I know that an element is an zero divisor. How can I formally prove that it is not invertible?

Comment: @Y.X. That is actually a great exercise to try out! I'll give you a start: Let $a$ be a zero divisor and suppose for contradiction that $a$ is invertible. Then $ab=0$ for some $b \neq 0$. Furthermore, we have some $a^{-1}$ such that $a^{-1}a=1$. How can we combine these facts to get a contradiction?

Comment: @ASKASK Is that $1=0$? we have $a^-1*a*b=0$ but $b$ is not zero hence invertible. So we have $a^-1*a=1=0*b^-1=0$, which cannot happen in a non-zero ring.

Comment: Almost. "We have that b is not zero hence invertible" isn't necessarily true. You're definitely on the right track though: look at that first equation you wrote.